# XSLT: Apply the same template to nodes with different names

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to apply the same xsl:template to different nodes of an xml tree, preferably selecting by an attribute of the node. Here's an example of the XML tree:

```
<journal>
    <claimantmonth>
        <By format="lookup">Bank dr/cr</By>
        <Month format="inputRO">4</Month>
        <Year format="inputRO">2012</Year>
        <claimslist>
            <claim>
                <id format="hidden">867</id>
                <enteredDate format="dateRO">2012-06-11</enteredDate>
                <enteredBy format="lookup">chris</enteredBy>
                <expenseDate format="date">2012-04-02</expenseDate>
                <description format="text">Electric Co</description>
            </claim>
       </claimslist>
    </claimantmonth>
   </journal>
```

I would want to use the same template for enteredDate and expenseDate, but a different one for description etc.

I am very new to XSLT and I have searched in vain for an answer, so I just need a pointer to where to look.

I found lots of examples of how to apply a variety of different templates to the SAME node. but that is not my problem.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your XSLT. By the way, none of your nodes have any attributes (per the usual definition of 'attribute'). What is an example of such a node?

Comment: You can use `<xsl:template match="enteredDate | expenseDate">...</xsl:template>`. As for "selecting by an attribute of the node", I don't see any attributes at all in your XML snippet.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I accidentally copied the wrorng version. Now edited to show the attributes. As for the XSLT, I do not think I have anything to show but in pseudo code it would look something like this:

inputRO: <xsl:format-def><input type="hidden" value="<xsl:value-of current node>" name="<xsl:pathtonode>_<xsl:iterationnumber>" /></xsl:format-def>

I am still reading and I think I need to understand XPATH a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You can match several elements like this:

```
<xsl:template match="enteredDate|expenseDate">
```

and you can match by the value of an attribute like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@class='sombre']">
```

> I am very new to XSLT and I have searched in vain for an answer

I think the fact that you are asking these questions means that your strategy for learning the language isn't ideal. I think you're trying to learn by googling for examples. That really doesn't work well - you'll find sites written by experts for experts, sites written by fools for fools, and every other combination; you will very rarely come across a site that takes you by the hand and teaches you the concepts in a structured, well-thought-out and peer-reviewed way. And until you know the concepts, you don't know what terms to use in a search. How could you have known that you need to google for "union pattern"? Get yourself a good book instead.

Comment: This (<xsl:template match="*[@class='sombre']">) looks like what I was searching for. You may be right about a good book, but (a) my experience of books is much the same as the web, some are best values a toilet paper, and (b) I am in Indonesia but my Indonesian is not up to the level needed for reading technical books. So, I do what I can do. Anyway thanks for the matching pattern. I will work on that.